# boto3_kinesis_client.list_streams is not returning the expected stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli, amazon-kinesis

When I use AWS CLI, for example, `aws kinesis list-streams`, I get two streams:

```
{
    "StreamNames": [
        "stream_a",
        "stream_b"
    ],
    "StreamSummaries": [
        {
            "StreamName": "stream_a",
            "StreamARN": "arn:aws:kinesis:eu-central-1:xxx:stream/stream_a",
            "StreamStatus": "ACTIVE",
            "StreamModeDetails": {
                "StreamMode": "PROVISIONED"
            },
            "StreamCreationTimestamp": "2021-08-03T13:42:02+02:00"
        },
        {
            "StreamName": "stream_b",
            "StreamARN": "arn:aws:kinesis:eu-central-1:xxx:stream/stream_b",
            "StreamStatus": "ACTIVE",
            "StreamModeDetails": {
                "StreamMode": "PROVISIONED"
            },
            "StreamCreationTimestamp": "2019-04-26T14:58:05+02:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, calling `list_streams(ExclusiveStartStreamName="stream_a")` is only returning the `stream_b`.

###### Additional information

AWS CLI version: `aws-cli/2.10.1 Python/3.9.11 Linux/5.19.0-41-generic exe/x86_64.ubuntu.22 prompt/off`

`boto3==1.26.116`

Comment: What do you think the `Exclusive` as part of the `ExclusiveStartStreamName` means?

Comment: From the docs ( https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/kinesis/client/list_streams.html ), " ExclusiveStartStreamName (string) – The name of the stream to start the list with. "

Comment: And if I call " list_streams(ExclusiveStartStreamName="stream_b") ", I get no streams in the response

Comment: In plain English it means whatever value you put there is NOT returned, that is literally what "exclusive" means. If I tell you to start counting up from 3 exclusive you say 4 5 6 ....

Comment: Solution: just don't specify `ExclusiveStartStreamName` at all.

Comment: And what does " The name of the stream to start the list with " mean in plain English?

Comment: I don't care. You have a parameter that is called `Exclusive...`, and the behaviour of the API matches that naming. Don't rely on documentation, especially when dealing with AWS. And if you read more than just a single line from the docs you will also see *"If there are more streams available, you can request more streams by using the name of the last stream returned by the ListStreams request in the ExclusiveStartStreamName parameter in a subsequent request to ListStreams"* - that would make no sense if the stream with the given name would be returned again.

Comment: Then your proposal is a hack, not a solution.

Comment: Whaaat? The way to use that API is to call it without any start key first and then continue calling it with the last stream name until you get no more returned (or use the NextToken). That is not a hack, that is the way this is supposed to work. That is how basically each and every of AWS pagination APIs work.

Comment: This is really not intuitive for me at all :sweat_smile: I now understand that the " ExclusiveStartStreamName " works by filtering out all streams up to and including that name. Thank you :)